# Flutter Material primary color not applied to text field cursor or selection

Tags: flutter, colors, material-design, themes

I assumed that the ThemeData of a Flutter MaterialApp could be used to define the primary color of the entire app just by setting the primaryColor argument.

However it doesn't seem to work, for example with cursor and selection colors of text fields. I noticed there are other arguments like cursorColor, textSelectionColor, textSelectionHandleColor, but what is the purpose of setting the primaryColor if we must also set a whole bunch of other arguments to make it work?

In any case it works as expected with CupertinoApp, so why not with MaterialApp?

```
void main() {
  if (true) {
    runApp(MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.red,
        accentColor: Colors.red,
        /*
        // Why must we add the following parameters?
        cursorColor: Colors.red,
        textSelectionColor: Colors.red.shade100,
        textSelectionHandleColor: Colors.red,
        */
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Material :-(')),
        body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Text')),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  } else {
    runApp(CupertinoApp(
      theme: CupertinoThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        primaryColor: Colors.red,
      ),
      home: CupertinoPageScaffold(
        navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
          leading: Icon(CupertinoIcons.circle_filled),
          middle: Text('Cupertino :-)'),
        ),
        child: SafeArea(child: CupertinoTextField()),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Try using primarySwatch, it will use a MaterialColor, if a value is null, let's say textSelectionColor, it will handle a shade based on that primarySwatch

Comment: Thanks @EdwynZN, it works better with primarySwatch (I confused it with primaryColor) however not 100% because the cursor is still blue...

Comment: yeah I see now, check https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/ThemeData.html about the implementation of the colors, some arguments use primaryColor or a shade of primarySwatch when null, but in the case of cursor it uses a specific blue color if null, no way to change it but to change the aprameter in ThemeData()